# React native record audio with showing audio visualizer/waveform

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I unable to design an audio visualiser when record audio from device.
I have go through many react native audio visualiser but unable to add visualiser when record audio. I need to show visualiser when recording audio.

Comment: Looking for the same. did you find any solution??

Comment: @FortuneCookie Yes after research lots on google, I got the library react-native-siri-wave-view used with react-native-audio library. I have calculate the decibels from audio currentPeakMetering values and set in the amplitude props of siri-wave-view.

Following are the reference url : 

[https://github.com/prscX/react-native-siri-wave-view]
[https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio]

Comment: Thats great! Can you please elaborate how you calculated the decibels. It will be great if you can share the code.

Comment: Following is the formula to calculate the decibel :

AudioRecorder.onProgress = (data) => {
 let decibels = 10 * Math.log10(data.currentPeakMetering / data.currentMetering) * -0.25
}